# in React, getting warnings about components I do not have

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, swagger-ui

in my React app I get these warnings:

`componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed ...`
and
`componentWillUpdate has been renamed ...`

about components named `Connect(a)` and `Provider`, but I do not have such components in my code.
after some search I found out it has something to do with Redux but I don't use Redux either so my guess is some dependencies use it.

i'm using:
`react, swagger-ui-react`

Can I fix those warnings or ignore them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of react you are using?

Comment: @SwarajGandhi 17.0.1

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops
It is going to be deprecated soon, the warning must have been about that only

Comment: I think you are using redux here, so that's why you getting those errros

Comment: They are just warnings, and it seems they are from 3rd party code. There isn't much you can do. You can (1) ignore and hope the package is updated soonish, (2) file an issue and hope it is resolved soonish, (3) fork the repo, fix it yourself and open a PR and hope it is merged and published soonish, (4) ditch it and move on to another package.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you, I think I'll just ignore them.